# How can i fix this dropmenu display problem?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, navbar

i've a problem with this dropmenu here:
[Background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRArG.png)

The problem is that it doesn't show me the categories of my submenu,

Navbarsubitem.js:

```
import React from 'react'
function NavBarSubItem(props)
{
return(
    <div className={props.subLi.liClassName}>
        <a className={props.subLi.aClassName} href={props.subLi.href}> </a>
    </div>
)
}
export default NavBarSubItem
```

Navbaritem.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import NavBarSubItem from './NavBarSubItem'
function NavBarItem(props)
{
function responsitiveMenu(){
    var x = document.getElementById("idTopnav");
    var y = document.getElementById("idIconItem");
    if(x.className === "topNav") {
        x.className += "-responsitive";
        y.className = "fa fa-fw fa-reply"
    }else{
        x.className += "topnav";
        y.className= "fa fa-fw fa-bar"      
    }
}

const NavBarSubItems = props.li.subItems.map(item => <NavBarSubItem key={item.id} subLi={item}/>);
return(
    <div className={props.li.liClassName}>
      <a className={props.li.aClassName} href={props.li.href} onClick={props.li.liClassName === "responsitive-icon" ? responsitiveMenu : ""} ><i className={props.li.icon} id={(props.li.liClassName === "responsitive-icon") ? "idIconItem":""}></i>{props.li.text}</a>
        <div className="dropDownItem-content">
            {props.li.liClassName === "dropDownItem" ? NavBarSubItems: ""}
        </div>
    </div>
)
}
export default NavBarItem
```

Navbarblock.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import NavBarItem from './NavBarItem'
function NavBarBlock(props){
const navBaritems = props.block.navItems.map(item => <NavBarItem key={item.id} li={item}/>);
return(
    <div className={props.block.id}>
        {navBaritems}
    </div>
)
}
export default NavBarBlock
```

Navbar.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import NavBarData from '../data/NavBarData'
import NavBarBlock from './NavBarBlock'
import './Nav.css'
class NavBar extends React.Component {
render (){
const navBarBlock = NavBarData.map(item=><NavBarBlock key={item.id} block={item}  
        img={item.imgSrc}></NavBarBlock>) 
    return (
        <nav className='topNav' id='idTopNav'>
            <h2>{navBarBlock}</h2>
        </nav>
    )
    }
    }
    export default NavBar
```

in the end i put my  in my app.js
if u need my css code i'll insert,
How could i resolve this problem? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I think of a dropdown menu, I think of this code and the classic Frank Reynolds' Egg from Always Sunny (Just a jumping off point!)

Inside my navbar component render:

```
<div className="dropdown-content">
    <a href="">Utility</a>
    <a href="">Utility2</a>
    <a href="">Utility3</a>
</div>
```

Inside my navbar.css

```
/* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #3e8e41;}
```

With this code, you'll get a basic dropdown menu. With which, you can then apply desired styling and functionality.

Comment: in the end I used your method for the dropdown and it was much easier for me, I probably did cofusion with the props and the css, thanks so much my friend!